# Переносимые типы данных и их использование в С++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, типы-данных, теория

Добрый день! Никак не могу найти ответ на этот вопрос, все уже облазил, может кто-нибудь поможет? Нашел только это : "Переносимые типы данных — это обобщенные типы данных, соответствующие в разных системах баз данных простым, совместимым между собой физическим типам. Физические типы данных — это типы данных, поддерживаемые целевой базой данных. Например, если установлен драйвер Access, все типы данных, доступные в Microsoft Office Access, будут доступны как физические типы данных в модели." - и то, не совсем понимаю суть того что написано. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: А где Вы этот вопрос получили, возможно от этого и будет ответ. Но в целом, как мне кажется, переносимые типы данных для Вас, это те, для которых размер и содержимое гарантированно на заданном наборе платформ. К примеру, int может быть как 2, так и 4 байтовый, а вот uint32_t - только 32байтовый.

Comment: Это вопрос к экзамену по кроссплатформенным системам=) То есть в Вашем примере unit32_t будем переносимым, я правильно понял?

Comment: да, только uint32_t, но в плюсах ещё много подобных типов.

Comment: А Вы не подскажете пару примеров, буду очень благодарен!)

Comment: здесь смотрите http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Вас интересуют типы, у которых написнао "exactly ... bytes"